# Create "custom" promise in selenium webdriver javascript bindings

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, promise

What is the proper way to create a "custom" promise in a selenium webdriver nodejs environment?

In a typical nodejs app, I would just create a promise that encloses all my async call like this:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    driver.method1().then(function(p1) {
       driver.method2(p2).then(function(p2) {
          resolve(p2);
       });
    });
});
```

and I was wondering, if this is the proper way to go in selenium as welland async-code is actually some selenium calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having looked at the source of the webdriver itself, it seems as if the way to go in webdriver would be as follows:

```
function async(p) {
   let deferred = webdriver.promise.defer();
   driver.method1(p).then(function(r1) {
      driver.method2(r1).then(function(r2) {
         deferred.fulfill(r2));
      });
   });
   return deferred.promise;
}

async(p).then(function (result) {});
```

but I would love to get some confirmation on this.

Comment: Yes, This is how I do it with angular's promises. (resolve replace fulfill in angular $q service).